# Camera yMin position should be restricted to player position

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing an android game on Unity, where the player jumps upon tapping and the camera follows the player. What I've done so far is restrict/clamp the camera's vertical movement, using `yMin = 0` and `yMax = 2`. The camera also follows the player smoothly.
What I want now is that when player changes its position, camera position changes and update the lower limit yMin to the current position of player. This way, if the player falls below and outside of view, the camera doesn't follow them down to the initial value.
here is my code for camera follow.

```
public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField]
    private float yMin;
    [SerializeField]
    private float yMax;
    [SerializeField]
    private float xMin;
    [SerializeField]
    private float xMax;
    private Transform target;

    void Start () {         
        target = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;
    }

    void LateUpdate () {

        Vector3 targetPos = new Vector3 (
            Mathf.Clamp(target.position.x, xMin, xMax),
            Mathf.Clamp(target.position.y, yMin, yMax),
            -10
        );

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPos, 0.02f);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)){
            Application.Quit ();    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I just figured it out that I should assign camera y position to yMin.

```
Update(){
yMin = GetComponent<Camera>().transform.position.y;
}
```